# @ExceptionHandler with VndErrors does not handle errors

Tags: spring-boot, error-handling, spring-hateoas

The problem: in the following example the handlers (if commented out) with `void` return type work without problems. I get `HttpStatus` 422.

If I switch to use the version with `VndErrors` the handlers do not work anymore and I get `HttpStatus` 500, and I can't find the reason for this behavior.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RequestMapping(produces = "application/vnd.error")
@ResponseBody
public class CurrencyCalculatorControllerAdvice {

    // this works
    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    private void handleCurrencyDetailsNotFoundException(CurrencyDetailsNotFoundException e) {}

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    private void handleCurrencyRateNotFoundException(CurrencyRateNotFoundException e) {}

    // this does not work
    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    VndErrors handleCurrencyDetailsNotFoundException(CurrencyDetailsNotFoundException e) {
        return new VndErrors(e.getLogRef().assemble(), e.getMessage());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    VndErrors handleCurrencyDetailsNotFoundException(CurrencyRateNotFoundException e) {
        return new VndErrors(e.getLogRef().assemble(), e.getMessage());
    }
}
```